# Add a side-effect to a Flux after each element is consumed?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

This is a simplified example but it illustrates the point.

Let's say I have a method defined like this:

```java
Flux<String> generateFlux() {
  return Flux.just("hello", "world"); // (S)
}
```

Is there a way to make `S` for example print something *after* an element has been consumed without the subscriber of the flux having to do or know anything about it?

For example, I'd to modify `S` so that this:

```java
generateFlux().doOnNext(System.out::println).block()
```

actually prints out this to the console:

```
hello
consumed
world
consumed
```

Is this possible to do this using Reactor 3.3 and if so how?

### Update

I guess my question was unclear so I'll add some more details. The gist of my question is that I want this to be *unchanged*:

```java
generateFlux().doOnNext(System.out::println).block() // A
```

So I want to modify `S`, i.e. `Flux.just("hello", "world")` to accommodate what I'm asking, not `A`. I know you can add `subscribe` and `doOnNext` etc to `A`, but this is *not* what I'm asking. I'm asking if there's a way to modify `S`, so that without any changes made to `A`, this will be printed when the subscriber/consumer of `A` has processed all items:

```
hello
consumed
world
consumed
```

I.e. that `S` somehow receives a signal that the first element has been consumed ("hello"), and then it can perform a `doOnNext` (or whatever) and in this case print "consumer". When the second element has been consumed ("world") then it should print "consumed" again.

Is this possible?

Comment: I would appricate some info on why this is downvoted since I don't know what I should change to make the question better.

Answer (score 1):

A Flux is a publisher and the correct way to consume data from a flux is using subscribe.
So

```
 generateFlux.subscribe(word -> {
      System.out.println(word);
      System.out.println("consumed" + word);
});
```

using subscribe with passing just a Consumer as a parameter you will override what the subscriber will do on next.
Basically behind will be created a Subscriber with having those 2 prints as a behaviour.
How Flux works you need to understand this 2 interfaces

```
   public interface Publisher<T> {
       void subscribe(Subscriber<? super T> var1);
   }

   public interface Subscriber<T> {
       void onSubscribe(Subscription var1);
 
       void onNext(T var1);
 
       void onError(Throwable var1);

       void onComplete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `doOnEach` to add side effects to every element consumed in the given stream without modify the publisher (error and completion too).

```
  Flux.just("hello", "world")
                .doOnEach(item -> System.out.println(item))
                .blockLast();
```

[doOnEach Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Also there are lot of overloads for the different life cycles, like doOnError, doOnSuccess, doOnNext...

[Documentation of Flux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html), you can find there all the operators and descriptions to those.

**Update:**

According to your update, you may think to the cross-cuting concern.
You can use `Hooks` to modify the reactive stream operators on assembling time.

[Hooks Doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#hooks-assembly)

Answer (score 0):

You can use doOnNext callback to intercept the action of the publisher pushing the next element. but use subscribe instead of block

```
generateFlux()
.doOnNext(next => System.out.println("Next Element pushed by publisher" + next))
.subscribe();
```

You can use the subscribe signature that overrides all behaviour of onNext, onError & onCompleted. subscribe method is overloaded in Flux